# opencv train cascade in less than 2 hours

Tags: opencv

I'm new to opencv I want to detect a fire object and I'm training a fire classifier using opencv traincascade, as I read various tutorials everyone said that training will use up days or even weeks.

I have 700 positives and 3k negatives, I read that I should not use all positive to train and ratio of 1:2 in positive negative so this is what I inputted

opencv_traincascade -data classifier -positive.vec -bg negatives.txt -numPos 500 -numNeg 1000 -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -precalcValBufSize 1024\ -precalcIdxBufSize 1024 -mode ALL PAUSE

the training only took 2 hours, Do I need to worry about it? is there something wrong with my samples?

Comment: What's the size of the images? If they're like 10x15, then you might be fine. If they're bigger (>100x100), then it will take forever.

Best way to find out if your classifier's good is to use it on some sample images.

Comment: I'm having problem with trying it ou using opencv sample codes as it doesn't work  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563678/opencv-detectmultiscale?noredirect=1#comment56879187_34563678